# How to save datetime to file in Python for use in script automation

Tags: python, datetime, automation

I'm creating a script that periodically scrapes a server for "new" files that have been added. To do so, I wish to store the datetime of my last script execution in a file, so that the script can process "all new files" since that datetime. The end goal is to run this script periodically via Windows Task Scheduler.

I'm able to do a basic version of this using the code below. However, I would expect there to be a cleaner, shorter or more robust way of achieving this. Any suggestions are welcome!

```
import datetime

fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
last_run = ""

# try loading the datetime of the last run, else print warning
try:
    with open("last_run.txt", mode="r") as file:
        last_run = datetime.datetime.strptime(file.read(), fmt)
        print(last_run)
except:
    print("no file available")


# ... run script code using the last_run variable as input ...


# update the script execution time and save it to the file
with open("last_run.txt", mode="w") as file:
    file.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt))
```

Comment: Your approach is fine. Make two functions out of it, put them in a module if you want to get them out of the way, and you're done.

Comment: Other than that, this question is off-topic on SO, since it's highly opinion-based ([help/on-topic]). There is no "one right way" to do this - your approach works and it looks reasonable, that's as good as it gets here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution looks fine.

The only thing that I would like to suggest to take out reading and writing last run time stamp logic in two separate functions and move those two functions in a separate module file. This is same as per suggestion from @Tomalak in the above reply. Below is the example with code.

Module file: last_run.py

```
import datetime

fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"


def get_last_run_time_stamp():
    """
    Get last run time stamp\n
    ====\n
    When this function called\n
    AND  last_run.txt file is present\n
    Then open the file and read the time-stamp stored in it\n
    ====\n
    When this function is called\n
    AND last_run.txt file is not present\n
    Then print the following message on console: "last_run.txt file is not available"\n
    """
    # try loading the datetime of the last run, else print warning
    try:
        with open("last_run.txt", mode="r") as file:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(file.read(), fmt)
    except:
        # Return with current time-stamp if last_run.txt file is not present
        return datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt)


# ... run script code using the last_run variable as input ...

def save_last_run_time_stamp():
    """
    Save last run time stamp\n
    ====\n
    When this function called\n
    AND  last_run.txt file is present\n
    Then Open the file, save it with current time stamp and close the file\n
    ====\n
    When this function called\n
    AND  last_run.txt file is not present\n
    Then Create the file, open the file, save it with current time stamp and close the file\n
    """
    # update the script execution time and save it to the file
    with open("last_run.txt", mode="w") as file:
        current_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt);
        file.write(current_timestamp)
```

Then, below is the file configured and run by schedular:

run_latest_scaped_files.py,

```
import last_run as lr

last_run = lr.get_last_run_time_stamp()
print(last_run)

# ... run script code using the last_run variable as input ...

lr.save_last_run_time_stamp()
```

That's it!!!